# PostgreSQL large single transaction slower than multiple transaction

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

On Postgres, I recently saw a case where there was a huge amount of selects being handled in a single transaction. This was really slow, so the solution was to break the selects into multiple transactions, which dramatically improved the query time.

Has anyone come across such a case? It seems counter intuitive and I was wondering if there was a technical reason as to why multiple transactions are preferable?

My only theory is that it's easier for the DB to maintain ACID properties with multiple transactions as opposed to a single gargantuan transaction.

Comment: It is strange. Can you show some test case? It looks like wrong PostgreSQL configuration - low wal_buffers, checkpoint_segments, shared_buffers or some similar.

Comment: Other possibility is a impact of serializable level - what version of PostgreSQL do you use?

Comment: As always a performance question without no information at all deserves no attention at all.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info then edit your question accordingly. `SELECT version()`, explain analyze outputs, log messages, text of the queries, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect selects themselves to be the issue if there is nothing writing to the database.  There aren't any locking issues there to speak of in a pure select statement.  The issues happen when there are writes.

If you have writes, you also have to deal with the fact that autovacuum cannot clean up items that are written after the oldest write transaction is started.

If you are seeing issues like this, it is critical to investigate locks (in `pg_locks`) so you can look into the queries and functions and find out where these are coming from.

Keep in mind a `SELECT` is not always just a `SELECT` and it is easy to assume too much about where performance problems are coming from.